# How can I use a predicate in a crm sdk 2011 linq query when the query contains a join?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

After reading around I found that I could not use the `.Contains` method when querying CRM 2011 with the SDK Linq provider. This is a problem as I need to query for records which belong to a collection of Guid’s that get passed from my application. After more investigating I discovered LinqKit and the Predicate Builder; great! Using a single entityset in a query the predicate works fine:

```
var visits = Context.Crm_scheduled_visitSet.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

The problem I have is when I expand the query to include a join to another entityset I cannot get the query to run when I include the predicate.
This is my query without the predicate which runs fine but I need to filter the `Crm_scheduled_visitSet` on a collection of Guid’s:

```
var scores = Context.Crm_scheduled_visitSet
    .Join(Context.crm_business_risk_scoreSet, v => v.Crm_scheduled_visitId.Value, s => s.crm_business_risk_score_id.Id, (v, s) => new
    {
        OrgID = v.Crm_client_id.Id,
        VisitStartdate = object.Equals(null, v.crm_actual_start_date) ? new DateTime() : v.crm_actual_start_date.Value,
        SectionId = s.crm_business_risk_section_id.Id,
        RisLevelId = s.crm_business_risk_level_id.Id,
        RiskRatingId = s.crm_business_risk_rating_id.Id
    });
```

What I need to do but this doesn't run:

```
var scores = base.Context.Crm_scheduled_visitSet.AsExpandable().Where(predicate)
    .Join(base.Context.crm_business_risk_scoreSet, v => v.Crm_scheduled_visitId.Value, s => s.crm_business_risk_score_id.Id, (v, s) => new
    {
        OrgID = v.Crm_client_id.Id,
        VisitStartdate = object.Equals(null, v.crm_actual_start_date) ? new DateTime() : v.crm_actual_start_date.Value,
        SectionId = s.crm_business_risk_section_id.Id,
        RisLevelId = s.crm_business_risk_level_id.Id,
        RiskRatingId = s.crm_business_risk_rating_id.Id
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get this to work, resorted to using query expressions. I hope the CRM sdk Linq provider is improved in the future be more in line with features offered by Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Well. you can get the visits alone first and join it with the other entity but with another

way of coding as follows.

```
var visits = Context.Crm_scheduled_visitSet.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);

var scores = from v in visits join r in Context.crm_business_risk_scoreSet
             on v.Crm_scheduled_visitId.Value equals r.crm_business_risk_score_id.Id
         select new {};
```

Note : Make sure to use the word "equal" in join and not to use this operator "=".

try it and waiting your feedback !

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried this already and it throws an exception. If this was Linq to entities it would work but because I am using the crm sdk linq provider there seems to be limitations. The error I get is: The method 'Join' cannot follow the method 'Where' or is not supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported methods.